# List destination UDP port number who have been visited more

Tags: udp, tcpdump

I have captured traffic, which contains udp packet.

I want to find destination UDP port numbers who have been visited more than others, using tcpdump.

**Edit1:**

I try following command, but the result seems to be wrong, what is the problem with it?

```
tcpdump -nr 200302161400.dump 'udp' | cut -f5 -d' ' | cut -f5 -d'.' | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) port[$i]++} END {for(k in port) print k,port[k]}' |sort -k2,2nr -k1,1 | head -10
```

Comment: And what is the specific question? This is currently too broad.

Comment: How can I list distination UDP port number who have been visited more using tcpdump?

Comment: In my opinion too broad to be answered here. What have you tried yourself? Any research you've done? Things you've looked up and have read?

Comment: As I understand I should write bash script to count number of time each port has been visited, and then sort to find most visited port, but I don't know how to write this script

Comment: I add the command which I try, but the result seems to be wrong.